# How to get Vue.js Markdown editor to recognize inputted JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am attempting to build a simple coding editor using properties of Vue.js that would otherwise be used to build typical markdown editors. I want my editor to be able to recognize JavaScript code when it is inputted on the code site. How can I achieve this? Here is my code so far. Thanks!

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid grid-list-md>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs6>
        <v-card>
          <v-textarea v-model="input" auto-grow="true" background-color="grey-light"></v-textarea>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs6>
        <v-card>
          <v-textarea v-html="input" auto-grow="true" disabled="true"></v-textarea>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      input: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: When you say "recognised" what exactly would you like to happen? Code highlighting? auto-formatting? Auto-complete? 

All of these require different answers

Comment: @FullStackFool, allow me to clarify: I want to turn this into a legit code editor that allows me to write HTML, CSS and JS all on the same page. I tried adding code for a simple responsive navigation bar to the editing side, which includes a mix of HTML, CSS, and JS. The HTML and CSS appear to render fine, but the JavaScript does not execute. What can I do to enable this editor to execute JavaScript functions?